# Lookup IP Address using ONLY the hostname; must do for 200+ servers

Tags: cmd, terminal, command, ip, hostname

What command would I use...if I want to find multiple IP addresses using just their hostname?  Ping or nslookup will work with only one hostname..I have over 200 hosts to look at and I need their IPs.

Is there a way to execute multiple IPs address from just their hostname one time, instead of typing each hostname manually?

Answer (score 0):

you need a loop around nslookup.  You can borrow a powershell script that creates a ForEach loop that runs a similar function for each host name you put in a file, powershell will write it out the IPs to a file.  I suggest starting with this one: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Resolve-IP-Addresses-from-df4cbbe5 -and get fancier from there.